# Unknown number of results into 3 columns creating 4 columns instead MySQL/PHP

Tags: php

I have a query that fetches some data from a table and I would like to display the data evenly over 3 columns however if the num of returned results is not equally divisible by 3 the script creates a forth column. My script is:

```
$columnCount = 0;
$howManyPerColumn = mysqli_num_rows($get_category_query) / 3;

<div class="listingCategoryListWrapper">
  <ul class="categoryList">
    <?php
      while($get_category_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_category_query)){
          $columnCount++;
          if($columnCount <= $howManyPerColumn){
            echo('<li><input name="txtCategory[]" type="checkbox" />List item</li>');
          }
          else
          {
            echo('</ul></div><div class="listingCategoryListWrapper"><ul class="categoryList"><li><input name="txtCategory[]" type="checkbox" />List item</li>');
            $columnCount = 1;
          }
      }
    ?>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this way?

At the top:

```
$columnCount = 1;
```

and then:

```
while($get_category_result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_category_query)){

      if($columnCount <= $howManyPerColumn){
        echo('<li><input name="txtCategory[]" type="checkbox" />List item</li>');
        $columnCount++;
      }
```

you can control it better this way:

```
 $howMany = mysqli_num_rows($get_category_query);
 $howManyPerColumn = $howMany / 3;
 $theInt = floor($howManyPerColumn * 3);
 if(($theInt * 3) < $howMany)$howManyPerColumn+=1;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks however now it adds 1 extra into the second column.

Answer (score 0):

Used original code, just added ceil to number per column

```
$howManyPerColumn = ceil(mysqli_num_rows($get_category_query) / 3);
```